# Why can we go from composition of functions to products in this proof about convolutions?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, fourier-analysis, weak-convergence, geometric-measure-theory

The following is taken/paraphrased from page 18 of *Geometry of Sets and Measures in Euclidean Spaces* by Mattila.

> **Theorem.** Let $\{\psi_\epsilon\}_{\epsilon>0}$ be an approximate identity and $\mu$ a Radon measure on $\mathbb{R}^n$. Then the functions $\psi_\epsilon * \mu$ converge weakly to $\mu$ as $\epsilon \to 0$, that is,
> $$\lim_{\epsilon \to 0} \int\varphi(\psi_\epsilon * \mu) \text{d}\mathcal{L}^n=\int \varphi \text{d}\mu$$
> for all $\varphi \in C_0(\mathbb{R}^n)$.
>
> *Proof.* We use Fubini's theorem, change of variable and the facts that spt $\psi_\epsilon \subset B(\epsilon)$ and $\int \psi_\epsilon \text{d}\mathcal{L}^n=1$ to compute
> $$\begin{equation}
> \begin{aligned}
> \int\varphi(\psi_\epsilon * \mu) \text{d}\mathcal{L}^n - \int \varphi \text{d}\mu &= \int \varphi(x) \int \psi_\epsilon(x-y) \text{d}\mu y\text{d}x - \int \varphi(y) \int \psi_\epsilon(x) \text{d}x\text{d}\mu y \textbf{ (1)} \\
> &= \cdots \text{ (Applying Fubini's theorem and arithmetic)} \\
> &= \iint_{B(\epsilon)}[\varphi(x+y)-\varphi(y)]\psi_\epsilon(x)\text{d}x\text{d}\mu y.
> \end{aligned}
> \end{equation}$$
> Then, as $\varphi$ is uniformly continuous, and $\int \psi_\epsilon \text{d}\mathcal{L}^n=1$, this goes to zero, so we have our result.

I am concerned about the equality marked $\mathbf{(1)}$ above. Why is it that the composition of the convolution and $\varphi$ ends up just looking like the product of the two integrals instead?

[**Edit:** My question here is why don't we have something like

$$\int\varphi(\psi_\epsilon * \mu) \text{d}\mathcal{L}^n - \int \varphi \text{d}\mu = \int \varphi(\int \psi_\epsilon(x-y)) - \int \varphi(y) \int \psi_\epsilon(x)$$

instead in step $\textbf{(1)}$? This might just be a basic arithmetic mistake on my part.]

Also, I don't really understand the deeper meaning of this theorem. What is its meaning?

Comment: Isn't convolution an integral? It's not a product of integrals; it's a nested or iterated integral.

Comment: @TedShifrin I clarified my question in an edit. Thank you for your help!

Comment: I don't understand your issue. They are writing $\int \phi(x)\int \psi(x-y)dy\,dx$ for a standard iterated integral. I would typically write this as $\iint \phi(x)\psi(x-y)\,dy\,dx$. Your parentheses aren't adding anything.

Comment: @TedShifrin Does that mean that on the LHS of the equation in the edit, the parentheses denote the product of $\phi$ and $\psi_\epsilon * \mu$, and not the function $\phi$ taking the value of $\psi_\epsilon * \mu$ as an input? If not, I don't understand what you're saying.

Comment: Yes, it’s always a product. In particular, since $\mu$ is a measure to start with, what you’re thinking doesn’t make sense. Now I see why you wanted parentheses, I guess. Did they type $d\mu y$ or $d\mu_y$? The former is not too meaningful.

Comment: They typed the former. Thank you for your help!